# How can I iterate this code so that I can save the value of last traded in the list dynamically?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

How can I iterate this code so that I can save the value of last traded in the list dynamically?

```
def get_ltp(data, strike_price):
    for d in data:
        if strike_price == d[5]:
            return d[5]
    n=get_ltp(data, '12000.00')
    n2=int(n.replace(',', ''))
    vol_opt.append(n2)
    print(vol_opt)
threading.Timer(5, get_ltp(data,'12000.00')).start()

get_ltp(data, '12000.00')
```

Comment: Format the code properly please.

Comment: @ The Tech Nerd code is now in the desired format.

Comment: What do you want the code to do? What does it do?

Comment: The code should iterate after every 5 seconds, vol_opt is a list, which contains the values of 'last price', after every 5 seconds code should provide the elements in the list.

Comment: So the code should basically run every 5 seconds?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194904/discussion-between-aditya-taide-and-the-tech-nerd).

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need one thread to run every 5 seconds, You can use a `While True:` clause with a `time.sleep()` to sleep for x seconds.

```
import time

def get_ltp(data, strike_price):
    for d in data:
        if strike_price == d[5]:
            return d[5]

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    get_ltp(data, '12000.00')
```